# Equation of a cylinder with a profile / ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, curves, spheres, ellipsoids

I have a geometry of a cylinder that is curved along both the lengths where there is generally a height of a cylinder. I am aware of the equation of a cylinder. I wanted to know what could the equation of a curved cylinder be as a function of the x,y, and z coordinates.? Also, could this curved cylinder be called an ellipsoid?

I have attached a geometry herewith along with the dimensions.

#### 2D

[image: 2D Geometry description]

#### 3D

[image: 3D Geometry Picture]

Comment: The shape is called a double radius (or a football shape). This is because it is a rotation of an arc and you need two radii to describe it.

Comment: @John Alexiou I have never heard the name "double radius" for such shapes. It could be called indeed **truncated** (at both ends) football shape. A "barrel shape" as given by Suzu Hirose is a very good choice.

Comment: @JeanMarie - I work with needle bearings which are [cylinders with a profile](https://d3i71xaburhd42.cloudfront.net/b2f49178334922478818e232f8f0fc97c9dc98e6/2-Figure1-1.png) or drop as it called. The contact surface is called a double radius because mathematically [it looks like this](https://www.tribonet.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Spherical-Contact-678x381.jpg.webp).

Comment: @John Alexiou Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That would probably be called a "barrel shape". The equation depends on the type of curve you choose for the barrel. If it's a circular curve, if the $y$ axis is along the axis of symmetry of the barrel and we count the centre of the barrel as the origin. then the equation for the barrel would be something like
$$x^2+z^2=r^2$$
for the $x$ and $z$ coordinates, and
$$(r+h)^2+y^2=R^2$$
Here $R$ is the radius of curvature of the barrel side and $h<R$ is a constant which expresses an offset from the origin of the centre of the radius of curvature.

So we end up like
$$(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}+h)^2+y^2=R^2.$$

In the case of your diagram, it looks like you have $h=80 \text{mm}$ and $R=90 \text{mm}$.

I couldn't persuade Wolfram Alpha to do a 3D plot of this, but [here is a 2D version](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28sqrt%28x%5E2%29%2B2%29%5E2%2By%5E2%3D3%5E2+from+y%3D-1+to+y%3D1).

[image]

In practice you would do this parametrically.

Comment: Thanks.  I am confused in the 2 equations by you and by @John? How can they be different although logically correct?

Comment: @user1085879 John Alexiou's equation is the same as mine. My $h=R-r$ in John Alexiou's notation, then just take square roots.

Comment: I see it now..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider the blue curve first

[image: fig1]

In my notation the small radius is $r=0.01$ and the large radius is $R=0.09$

It is an arc, of radius $R$ and center at $x=R - r$

I use the parameter angle $\theta$ for the sweep angle of the arc from the center.

The coordinates of the arc are

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{ (R-r) - R \cos \theta \\ R \sin \theta \\ 0} $$

Now apply a rotation about the *y*-axis to this arc to get the coordinates of the shape. The parameter angle of the rotation is $\varphi$

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \varphi & 0 & \sin \varphi \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -\sin \varphi & 0 & \cos \varphi \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{ (R-r) - R \cos \theta \\ R \sin \theta \\ 0}$$

or

$${\rm surf}( \varphi, \theta) = \pmatrix{x=-\cos \varphi ( R \cos \theta - R + r) \\ y=R \sin \theta \\ z=\sin \varphi (R \cos \theta -R + r)} \tag{1} $$

The surface is fully described by the parameters $\theta$ and $\varphi$. If you limit the length of the shape to $\ell$ then you find the limits of $\theta$ from

$$ \tfrac{\ell}{2} = R \sin \theta \tag{2} $$

So $\varphi = 0 \ldots 2\pi$ and $\theta = -\arcsin \left( \tfrac{\ell}{2 R} \right) \ldots \arcsin \left( \tfrac{\ell}{2 R} \right)$.

Here are the results of the parametric surface as viewed from the *z*-axis, for $R=10$ and $r=1$

[image: fig2]

---

From the *y* coordinate use $\theta = \arcsin \left( \tfrac{y}{R} \right)$

From the *z* coordinaten use $\varphi = - \arctan \left( \tfrac{z}{x} \right)$

the end relationship is

$$ \boxed{ \sqrt{R^2-y^2}-\sqrt{x^2+z^2}-R+r = 0 } \tag{3} $$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was wondering why your equation is different from the equation by Suzu Hiroze given in this same section? I put values for the 2 equations and they dont seem to be equivalent.

Comment: I am not convinced @Suzu is correct. I can only see the plot when $z=0$ which is a  special case. I plotted mine for various values of $z$ and I get the shapes I expected.

Comment: @user1085879 - if you plug (1) into (3) you can prove they are identical. (1) is the parametric form, and (3) is the implicit form. With some simplifications, you arrive at $R \cos \theta - ( R \cos \theta - R  +r) -R + r =0$ or $0=0 \; \checkmark$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, although I don't see any flaw in that equation as even if z is varied the maths is taken into consideration. But for my specific geometry if I put the values in the equations, for the Suzu equation I get 0, and for your equation, I get 1e-18 which we can say is almost zero. But I am interested as to which one is the correct one. Also in the cylindrical system for x coordinate, it should be r - R(1-cos(theta)),right? instead of R(1-cos(theta))-r?

Comment: Thanks. I understood that parametric and implicit form are same. But I am confused in the 2 equations by you and by @Suzu? How can they be different although logically correct?

Comment: @user1085879 the surface is symmetric for $x$ and $-x$, so either one would work. It depends on the convention for $\varphi$ used.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Btw, if the equation is sought for finding volume of a Barrel it can be done by integration with attention to limits, resulting in the formula

$$ V= \frac{\pi h }{12}\cdot (2D^2+d^2)$$
where $D$ is mid diameter, $d$ is top/bottom diameter and height $h$.